# How can I prevent devs from using a global?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a TypeScript project that uses a custom wrapper over `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to send messages. This custom wrapper makes sure the messages are formatted correctly, are safe, etc.

However there is a lot of turnaround of devs in the codebase and new devs often try to use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` directly (and not the wrapper).

Is there any way I can display a warning, either at compile time or in their IDE, when they try to access that method?

Comment: Write a linter rule? See e.g. https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use type annotation, below is an example used to avoid new Buffer(number) for Node.js

```
interface BufferConstructor {
        /**
         * Allocates a new buffer of {size} octets.
         *
         * @param size count of octets to allocate.
         * @deprecated since v10.0.0 - Use `Buffer.alloc()` instead (also see `Buffer.allocUnsafe()`).
         */
        new (size: number): Buffer;
}
```

If you use it, The IDE will give you a warning:
[image]